# Applescript: Open a Folder in Finder

Tags: applescript, directory, finder

I m trying to open a folder in Finder using AppleScript. The following is my code. I want the folder `WorkSpace` to open in Finder, but it opens the Parent Folder `/Volumes/MyMacDrive/Mani` and highlights the `WorkSpace` folder. I want the contents of `WorkSpace` folder, but all I'm getting is its Parent Folder's Contents. What am i missing here ..?

```
property the_path : "/Volumes/MyMacDrive/Mani/WorkSpace/"
set the_folder to (POSIX file the_path) as alias
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    if window 1 exists then
        set target of window 1 to the_folder
    else
        reveal the_folder
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Use the `Finder window` class instead of `window` to not have an error if one of these windows is open (information window, preferences window, clipping window and view options window).--> `if Finder window 1 exists then` .

The reveal command : Bring the specified object(s) into **view**, use the `open` command as in **adayzdone**'s answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I've searched, there seems to be no way to open the folder rather than just highlighting the folder in AppleScript. So I have used:

```
do shell script "open /Volumes/MyMacDrive/Mani/WorkSpace/"
```

It worked fine for me but please update me if i'm wrong.

Comment: There is no difference between your `do shell script` command and the `open` (not **reveal**) command in the Finder, it works for everyone.

But, maybe that's an exception to the rule.

Comment: For completeness, I'd like to add that if your path is a parameter, you can use `do shell script "open " & quote & pathParameter & quote` and it handles things like spaces in the path.

Answer (score 22):

It's actually simpler than it seems:

```
tell application "Finder" to open ("/Volumes/MyMacDrive/Mani/WorkSpace/" as POSIX file)
```

or use colons to give an AppleScript path:

```
tell application "Finder" to open "MyMacDrive:Mani:WorkSpace"
```

with that you have an open window

Comment: Well, I have use the second one and it did work for me (Mac OS X 10.10.3, AppleScript 2.4). Thank you!

Comment: I had to use something like this (Mojave):

`Macintosh HD:Users:MyUser:Downloads`. Replace "MyUser" with the actual name of your user's folder.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if front Finder window exists then
    set target of front Finder window to the_folder
else
    open the_folder
end if
```

Edited to incorporate jackjr300's correction. Finder window is the correct class to use.

Comment: While this is correct I edited it because it will not work without the `end if` and you will get an error that `the_folder` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me and bring the **Finder** to front.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open ("/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Figma/" as POSIX file)
end tell
```

I just put it in Shortcuts.